# Arraylist ConcurrentModificationException cause?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In my application, I have concurrent modification error. I have looked everywhere, but cannot find the root cause, therefore I need help.

```
13:15:50 [pool-11-thread-1] INFO  com.foo.Baz  - Some log
13:16:02 [pool-11-thread-1] ERROR com.foo.Bar  - java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:911)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:861)
    at com.foo.Bar.getListMyMethod(Bar.java:123)
13:17:11 [pool-11-thread-1] INFO  com.foo.Baz  - Some other log
```

Logs are above.

```
import org.jdom.Element;
import java.util.*;

public class Bar {

    private List<SomeObj> getListMyMethod() {
        List<SomeObj> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            List<Element> nodes = readXML("some_xml.xml");
            for (Element node : nodes) {
                SomeObj c = new SomeObj();
                for (String next : SomeObj.getAllFields()) { // line 123 is here
                    c.getProperties().put(next, node.getChildText(next));
                }
                result.add(c);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e, e);
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    // some other methods
}
```

The class that exception occured above.

```
public class SomeObj {
    protected static List<String> allFields = null;
    protected HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        allFields = new ArrayList<>();
        allFields.add("foo");
        allFields.add("bar");
        allFields.add("baz");
    }
    
    public SomeObj() {
    }
    
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public static List<String> getAllFields() {
        return allFields;
    }
    
    // some other methods
}
```

The class

```
public class ChildSomeObj extends SomeObj {

    static {
        allFields.add("additional_field");
    }
    // some other methods
}
```

I have checked the `allFields`. The only modification I can find to `allFields` is in the child classes of `SomeObj`.

There are other threads in my application, but from the logs, it seems that they are not accessing `SomeObj` at that time when the error occurred.

Is this a possible explanation: While thread 1 is iterating for `SomeObj.getAllFields()`, other thread or something accesses to `ChildSomeObj`, and since the `ChildSomeObj` is accessed, its static initialization happens and modifies `allFields`. However, since the child has access to `allFields` with `protected` modifier. So, it should have its own set of `allFields`, I am not sure :/

Comment: Your understanding "it should have its own set of allFields" is not correct, there is only 1 allFields instance in your case.

Comment: So, when someone accesses ChildSomeObj, its `static` fields are initialized and all `ChildSomeObj` and `SomeObj` in the view of class loader will have the same `allFields`. In other words, accessing `ChildSomeObj` will modify the static field of `SomeObj`, since it adds something to the list, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think you can write a simple program to verify it.

Comment: I checked. If I "create" a new child object, then `allFields` of both classes are modified. But if I access `allFields` from the Child's static method without creating it, then, `additional_field` is not added to `allFields`.